# Automatic move by datein range : Shell Script

Tags: shell, date, ubuntu

I have a folder with many files like this:
  00606E00C3B3()_0_20140721070542_8770.jpg

What i do manually is this:

```
  mkdir 140601
  mv *20140601*.jpg 140601/
```

For every day I need a script what is doing this automatically and i want to start it as command like:

```
 sh sort.sh datestart dateend
```

example:

```
 sh sort.sh 140601 140630
```

How can i do that thing? help please.

Comment: you can do it without much trouble. See: `man 1 date` and look at `date -s` to set the date string and then use `date %s` to convert to seconds since epoch. Get the value for start date, then end date. Then you can move files based on whether their date (converted with format `%s`) falls in between. A second simpler approach would be to read all filenames that match year (e.g. 2014) into an array, then parse `month` and `day` from the filename of each file and compare to your begin/end dates. Both just take a little work.

Comment: i got it now sir. thank you. i have a concern, is it possible to split the 140601 to 1406 as a display?

Comment: Yes. look at bash character string indexes. Say you have `var=140601` and you want `1406`. Simply do `newvar=${var:0:4}` which says in variable `var` start at the first char (`0`) and then give me `4` more. That is the `:0:4`

Comment: Addemdum: should read "start at the first char (`0`) and then give me 4 total"

Comment: If you get stuck with your script, drop another comment and I'll help you get it working.

Comment: thanks , :) i already have a working script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for filename in *_201*.jpg; do
    part=1${filename#*201} # YYMMDD and everything after
    yymmdd=${part:0:6}
    mkdir -p $yymmdd
    mv "$filename" $yymmdd/
```

Yes, this will fail after the year 2019, and if you have "201" as the numeric part before the year in a filename.  Those bugs are left as exercises.  :)

Comment: Wouldn't that move every file that matched `*_201*.jpg` into `$yymmdd` separating all files into daily dirs?? It looks like he wants them separated by month. (or by specified `start end` dates)

Comment: Maybe the OP wants separated by months, but he/she specified a directory name like `140601` which looks like YYMMDD to me.  Who knows, the code above can be adapted to suit by simply changing the `6` to a `4` for YYMM instead.

Comment: thanks , :) yes you're right i made it to YYMM for directory name.